# Using a $ symbol within RStudio snippets without the $ sign being evaluated as a variable creator

Tags: r, rstudio, code-snippets

When I create an R snippet in RStudio the following case, the $ sign from the snippet variable creates problems when I want a literal $sign to appear for use in my snippet (e.g., mtcars$cyl):

```
snippet cor_binary
    ltm::biserial.cor(${1:df}\$ ${2:continuous_field}, ${1:df}\$ ${3:binary_field}, use = c("complete.obs"), level = 2)
```

The above snippet produces an unwanted white space between `df` & `field`:

```
# output
ltm::biserial.cor(df$ continuous_field, df$ binary_field, use = c("complete.obs"), level = 2)
```

No space in my snippet produces a different problem in the output:

```
snippet cor_binary
    ltm::biserial.cor(${1:df}\$${2:continuous_field}, ${1:df}\$${3:binary_field}, use = c("complete.obs"), level = 2)

# output
ltm::biserial.cor(df\{2:continuous_field}, df\{3:binary_field}, use = c("complete.obs"), level = 2)
```

How can I include a $ sign in the context of mtcars$cyl without the snippet

Comment: You don't tell us what "code snippets" are.  Are these something in RStudio?  (If so, you should use that tag, not "r".)

Comment: I have updated the question accordingly. Thank you @user2554330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach would be to use `[[` instead of `$`:

```
snippet test
    ${1:df}[["${2:abc}"]]
```

Which resolves to:

```
df[["abc"]]
```

If `$` must be used here's a hacky way to get it working that takes advantage of the fact that snippets can run code using `` `r  ... ` `` which can be used to print a zero width element between the escaped $ and the second variable.  This probably shouldn't be relied upon though.

```
snippet test2
    ${1:df}\$`r ""`${2:abc}
```

Which resolves to:

```
df$abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks:

```r
data.table::data.table(`a$b` = 1)
```

```
   a$b
1:   1
```